# ForeFront TMG 2010 - Topology Question

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, microsoft-forefront-2010, microsoft-ftmg

[image]
Total 4 NICs
NIC1 - LAN interface
NIC2 - WAN 1 (ISP - A)
NIC3 - WAN 2 (ISP - B)
NIC4 - DMZ (ISP - C with Public IP Pool)

---

Hi All,

3 ISP Connections
2 For Internet use (Local LAN Internet Access – browsing, email etc)
1 WAN for DMZ (Where I will keep our servers on Public IP’s – as we have a Static Public IP Pool)
1 NIC for LAN Connection

So, as far as I have understood :

Q1) Do I have to add persistent routes on the Windows box hosting Forefront TMG to all networks (NICS) or can I do that in TMG MMC ?

Q2) Will the servers on Public IPs in DMZ be accessible to the internal lan or will they go out the internet and come back, or shall I specify a private range IP as well and the public static IP too ?

Will be grateful for your insight and help !
Kind Regards

Is this even possible ? I am hoping and will try to use the load-balance feature on WAN-1 and WAN-2, will create DMZ from the 3rd WAN

Will be grateful for your suggestions and thoughts

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do all your routing setup from within the TMG MMC. It then goes and adds the routes via the RRAS service for you.
2. If the NIC4 is configured correctly and TMG has firewall policies and network policies that permit it, the traffic will stay inside your network.

This is a fairly common setup, nothing out of the ordinary here.